# unable to link to my Windows 10 Universal app with a custom protocol using javascript

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-addin, deep-linking, windows-10-universal

I am working on an Office 365 mail add-in and I have a requirement to create a deep link to my windows 10 Universal app from this add-in.

I added the required custom protocol into my Win 10 app's manifest and its working fine for all browsers

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
     <uap:Protocol Name="myapp" />
</uap:Extension>
```

But when I am trying to call this protocol from a js file it is not opening my app. Here is the code

```
<head>
<script>
        function addToCartClick(productId) {

            **window.open("myapp:?" + productId, "_blank");** 
            //window.location.assign("myapp:?" + productId); // I tried this also
        }
    </script>    
</head>

<body>
    **<button onclick="addToCartClick(121212)">Add to cart</button>**
</body>
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have tried using window.location.href = "myapp:?121212" - didn't worked

I have also tried using "http://google.com" and this is the behaviour

[image: html]

[image: used http://google.com]

I have also enabled popup for the browser. I am using Microsoft Edge

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure popup is not [blocked by browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). It works well at my end. And you can also use

```
window.location.href = "myapp:?" + productId;
```

to replace the calling of

```
window.open("myapp:?" + productId, "_blank");
```

Comment: It tried your solution but its still not working. The block-popup is off. I have added some screenshots for the reference.

Comment: Please try to copy "myapp:?121212" in the address bar on Edge then click "enter", does your app successfully launch?